# How to implement many to one multiple selection scenario in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

**Scenario:** An Album has multiple songs. A Song has multiple artists and can have no or one album.

I implemented ManyToOne relationship using ForeignKey. Here are the models:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u'Artist Name')
    bio = models.TextField()

class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u'Album Name')
    description = models.TextField()

class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u'Song Name')
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, null=True)
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)
```

Now, in Django Admin, on New Album page, I want to select multiple songs for that album.

**Bonus Question:** I also need to get the artists of a given album. Is there any better way of doing it instead of getting all the artists from songs_set?

**Edit:** Updated Song - Artist to ManyToMany relationship.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but:  Why would a song have at most 1 album?  What about re-releases?  best-of? remix? compilations?

Comment: Because, that's the closest analogy that I could came up with to the original problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the admin docs, particularly the [`InlineModelAdmin` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).

```
from django.contrib import admin

class SongInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Song

class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        SongInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(Album, AlbumAdmin)
```

To answer your second question, you could span the relationships via the QuerySet filter call like so:

```
Artist.objects.filter(
    song_set__album=GIVEN_ALBUM
)
```

Comment: Actually Inlines do not solve my problem. I need something like select multiple widget instead of TabularInline. I guess, may be, I need to create an custom form AlbumAdmin. Thanks for your answers though.

Comment: Look into this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal

Comment: filter_horizontal only works for ManyToManyFields in my opinion. Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No you're right. My mistake. What about overriding the form field with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides ?